# How to make tweaks to a Docker base image?

Tags: docker

How would one go about making tweaks to a docker base image before or during `docker build`?

For instance, the **rails** Docker base image as-is will install Ruby 2.2. What if we want Ruby 2.1.5? Or, what if we want Ubuntu 12.04 instead of 14.04?

Another way of looking at this is how to create custom containers by tweaking the upstream of base images.

Comment: Can you just make your own base? If you want a rails on ruby 2.1.5 then make a base just like the rails base but use the right ruby v, then build off that image base. I am not aware of an option to go upstream and change what is already there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't and shouldn't. A docker image once built mustn't be changed since the idea is to have a consistent environment for our applications.

You can create your own docker file based on the rails image (most publicly available images will have their Dockerfile available to view too) and change the step that installs rails to suit you. Of course this will be a NEW image.

Comment: Thanks for understanding my question! This is an interesting issue, because if you have a step that you want to change early in the build order, it seems very likely to break the rest of the build

Comment: And that's exactly why it's a bad idea to modify the existing image. Start at a new baseline - building from an 'OS' base image, then installing _just_ the dependencies you want, is no bad thing.